# Change of Basis (Transformation Matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

I am having some confusion regarding change of basis, and am unsure how to execute the following question:

If $T\in \text{End}(V)$ such that $T(x_1)=2x_1+x_2$ and $T(x_2)=x_1$, and $y_1=4x_1+2x_2$ and $y_2=x_1-x_2$, determine the matrix $T$ with respect to the basis $\{x_1,x_2\}$ and with respect to the new basis $\{y_1,y_2\}$. Furthermore, it is possible to find an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP=B$, where $A$ is the matrix transformation with respect to the basis $\{x_1,x_2\}$ and $B$ is the matrix transformation with respect to the basis $\{y_1,y_2\}$.

For the first part, I know I need to find some matrix $D=C^{-1}AC$, such that $A$ is the transformation matrix with respect to the standard basis, and $C$ is the change of basis matrix, but I am unsure how to construct $C$ and thus $C^{-1}$. The transformation matrix for $T$ is:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1\\
    1 & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I apologize regarding the simplicity of the question and would appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the ‘standard’ basis for an abstract vector space?

Comment: Is it e_1,e_2,...,e_n? That is, (1,0,...,0),(0,1,...,0),...,(0,0,...,1)?

Comment: This makes sense for $\mathbf R^n$. But for an *abstract* vector space? All you know is it has dimension $2$.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix of $T$ in basis $(x_1,x_2)$   has for columns the coordinates of $T(x_1)$ and $T(x_2)$ in basis $(x_1,x_2)$. Thus
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\quad\text{(no standard basis in this)}.$$
For the basis $(y_1,y_2)$, use  the change of basis matrix  from basis  $(x_1,x_2)$ to basis  $(y_1,y_2)$: its column vectoes are the coordinates of $y_1$ and $y_2$ in basis $(x_1,x_2)$, i.e.
$$P=\begin{bmatrix}4&1\\2&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$ 
The change of basis formula asserts that the matrix of $T$ in the new basis is
$$B=P^{-1}AP,\quad\text{so }\quad A=PBP^{-1}.$$
All that remains to do is calculating the inverse of $P$.